# How can I add more Icingaweb2 user?

Tags: icinga, icinga2, icingaweb2

I am using Icinga2.

```
[Administrators]
users = "admin"
permissions = "*"
groups = "Administrators"
```

This one is configuration for IcingaWeb2 admin user Authorization.

I can login in using `admin` user. By their documentation, any user under Administrators group can login in with admin permissions.

How can I add more user in this group Administrators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project I have created 2 object, one to create user like

```
    object User "icingaadmin1" {
    display_name = "admin1"
    groups = [ "icingaadmins" ]  //user group 
    email = "abc@gmail.com"
    }
```

and other with

```
    object UserGroup "icingaadmins" {
    display_name = "Icinga2 Admin Group"
    }
```

So like this u can create multiple "object User" and add them to your user group "Administrators"

Comment: and how would I set a password for that new user? I cannot login using icingaweb